# Laravel 5.1 bool property in model returns empty array when accesed inside model class

Tags: laravel, model, this, laravel-5.1, typing

I have an eloquent model with a boolean field. The column in the database is a `tinyint(1)` and the value is stored correctly as `1`. If I access this value in any given context outside the class I get the correct value:

```
$myModel = MyModel::first();
var_dump($myModel->visible); //outputs 1
```

When I access it inside a method inside the model class though....

```
class MyModel {
    public function isVisible(){
        var_dump($this->visible); 
        // return $this->visible && $this->approved; // another true value
    }
}

//on tinker
>> $myModel->isVisible();
array(0) {
}
>>
```

I know this sounds crazy but I've been at it for two hours and cannot make it work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel's Model class already has a [`protected $visible`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L110) property. As you might have guessed, it's an array. When accessed from within the class, it has access to this `protected` property so it will return the array. When accessed outside the class, it uses PHP's magic `__get` method so it's returning the value of your column.

If possible, you could rename your column to prevent any potential future conflicts. Otherwise, you can change your `isVisible()` method by using the `getAttribute` method to access the model's column value rather than accessing the model's property like this:

```
public function isVisible(){
    return $this->getAttribute('visible') && $this->approved;
}
```

Comment: Oh man, it makes so much sense now. I never thought to look for an existing inherited property. Lesson learned!